# get params from a js function from a webpage

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to retrieve automatically some element onto a webpage, but I'm stuck with multiple things.

First I'm looping through all the classes named  with the help of document.getElementsByClassName('trList') that got the informations that i need.

Then into the multiple results i'm trying to extract the parameters contained in this :

```
<div id="action_0" onclick="cba.facture.controllers.factureListeController.createFactureListeTooltipActionDialog('73039508',
                         'action_0_TooltipDialog',
                         'action_0',
                         '190px', 'Télétransmise', '1', 'false', '0',
                         '7622', '14902', 'Télétransmise', '')" onmouseover="dijit.Tooltip.defaultPosition = ['above', 'below']">…</div>
```

I'm trying to get the 1st and 9th parameters of the onclick function.
And of course there are several iteration of this function in the results listed by the GetelementsByClassName.
I really don't have any clue on how to do this.

Could someone give me some direction on how to retrieve this?

Edit :
Trying to use the answer given earlier by @adriano009
i've got two problems :

First, the LET scope creates a bug in safari, telling me that i "can't create duplicate variable that shadows a global property”; so i'm using VAR for this one.

Second, with this code :

```
jsScript +="var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('trList');"; 
jsScript +="for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {";
jsScript += "let attr = slides[i].getAttribute('onclick'); ";
jsScript +=" console.log(attr);"; 
jsScript +="};";
```

Even though there are onclick attributes listed in slides.item(i), the log shows that it founds 0 attributes while trying to get them with slides[i].getAttribute('onclick'). Why's that?

Answer (score 0):

```
let all = document.getElementsByClassName("class_name");
for (let i=0, i < all.length; i++) {
    let attr = all[i].getAttribute("onclick"); 
    let first_param = attr.split[','][0];
    let ninth_param = attr.split[','][8];
    console.log(first_param, ninth_param);
}
```

Comment: The code seems good, but an answer is generally considered better if includes some explanation of what its code does and why it makes a good solution for the question.

Comment: Thanks, i'm learning but I understand a bit this code, it's listening to all the onclick attributes listed within the class, but still it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: I'm sorry i tried to answer in comments but the code looks like mess, so I've updated my question above, with the elements of your answer as i cannot make it work in my example